# on Android, how to make upnp mr response my m-search?

Tags: android, upnp, ssdp

I am working on Android. And tried to find media renderer in the same lan. 
I sent out m-search to 239.255.255.250:1900. I captured the message I sent as follow:

```
M-SEARCH * HTTP/1.1
MX: 5
ST: ssdp:all
MAN: "ssdp:discover
User-Agent: UPnP/1.0 DLNADOC/1.50 Platinum/0.6.8.0-bb / fenda0000
Host: 239.255.255.250:1900
Connection: close
```

However, no response from mr which do working there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My mistake, i bypassed the clients' response! Simonc's answer is useful, too.

Answer (score 2):

There's a typo in your `MAN` header.  It needs to have a closing `"`

```
MAN: "ssdp:discover"
                   ^
```

The `Connection: close` header is not required by the spec.  It also doesn't make much sense in a connectionless multicast UDP message.  That said, I don't think it'll cause any harm but you could try removing that if the fix to the `MAN:` header doesn't get things working for you.